# Using an array of ranges to create a formula to add cells from each sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to set an array to a set of ranges. I want to run through each of my sheets, starting at the 5th from the left and select the cell to the right of wherever it finds the text "Total" in column. then the last part is just taking this as it winds through the sheets and creates a string which when placed in the sheet "Final Budget", it acts like a formula and sums up all the values in that cell.

I am receiving the Run-time error '9' of subscript out of range. I have used the index property of Worksheets before so I believe I am doing that correctly, but am not sure why it cannot recognize the subscript.

---

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False     
Dim EmpFinal() As Variant
Dim total_1() As Variant
Dim total_2() As Variant
Dim totalAddress() As Variant
iSheets = Sheets.count
For i = 5 To iSheets - 1

    Set total_1(i) = Worksheets(i).Range("D:D")
    Set total_2(i) = total_1(i).Find("Total")
    totalAddress(i) = Cells(total_2(i).Row, total_2(i).Column + 1).Address(0, 0)
    Formula = "=SUM("
    Formula = Formula & Sheets(i).Name & "!" & totalAddress(i) & ","

Next i
Formula = Left(Formula, Len(Formula) - 1) & ")"
Worksheets("Final Budget").Range("I1").Formula = Formula

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: You must declare the size of the array before trying to insert values into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need the arrays as you are passing the values to the string inside the loop:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False     
Dim EmpFinal As Variant
Dim total_1 As Range
Dim total_2 As Range
Dim totalAddress As string
Dim iSheets as Long

iSheets = Sheets.count

Formula = "=SUM("
Dim i as Long
For i = 5 To iSheets - 1

    Set total_1 = worksheets(i).Range("D:D")
    Set total_2 = total_1.Find("Total")
    If Not total_2 is Nothing then
        totalAddress = worksheets(i).Cells(total_2.Row, total_2.Column + 1).Address(0, 0)
        Formula = Formula & "'" & workSheets(i).Name & "'!" & totalAddress & ","
    End If
Next i
Formula = Left(Formula, Len(Formula) - 1) & ")"
Worksheets("Final Budget").Range("I1").Formula = Formula

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Absolutely stunning! Would you know why I would return a run-time error 1004 right as it gets to to the second to last line? The Worksheet is spelled correctly and I don't see anything that would conflict with the formula trying to be placed there.

Comment: Look at `Formula` in the immediate window and make sure it looks correct.  If you have worksheets with spaces in the name we will need to make a little change.

Comment: @alcopo63q I changed it deal with worksheet names that have spaces.

Comment: I broke the code before it ended and the formula does seem to be correct up to a point. It gets cut off in the middle of a few sheets, but I don't know if that happens when you watch a variable in the "Watches" window (I am very new to VBA) and if it does have some sort of maximum size then that would be the problem.

Comment: @alcopo63q please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.